# Redbeanphp bad order

Tags: php, mysql, orm, redbean

With this code, I parse post elements from table

```
$all = R::findAll('postdate'," ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15");
    for($i = 1; $i <= count($all); $i++){
        if(isset($all[$i])){
            $date = date_create($all[$i]->date);
            $post = R::findOne('post', 'date_id = ?', array($all[$i]->id));
            $author = R::findOne('postauthor', 'id = ?', array($post->author_id));
            $title = R::findOne('posttitle', 'id = ?', array($post->title_id));
            echo '<div class=post>
                      <i class=post-date>'.date_format($date, 'd.m.Y G:i').'  '.$author->author.'</i>
                      <h1>'.$title->title.'</h1><hr><br>'.
                      $post->content.
                  '</div>';
        }
        
    }
```

but in the end the last posts are not found and everything goes in ascending order. Help me please. I tried it through the date too

Comment: Hey! This code snippet looks like it has been pulled from a larger codebase. Without the context, we may be unable to help. If you could turn it into a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $all = R::getAll( 'SELECT * FROM postdate ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 125' );
        for($i = -1; $i <= count($all); $i++){
            if(isset($all[$i])){
                $date = date_create($all[$i]['date']);
                $post = R::findOne('post', 'date_id = ?', array($all[$i]['id']));
                $author = R::findOne('postauthor', 'id = ?', array($post->author_id));
                $title = R::findOne('posttitle', 'id = ?', array($post->title_id));
                echo '<div class=post>
                          <i class=post-date>'.date_format($date, 'd.m.Y G:i').'  '.$author->author.'</i>
                          <h1>'.$title->title.'</h1><hr><br>'.
                          $post->content.
                      '</div>';
            }
        }
```